# Высветление текста на странице

Tags: jquery, javascript, css

Доброго всем времени суток господа

Обращаюсь в первую очередь к тем, кто знает такие ОС? как Win Vista / Win Vista Service Pack 7, с включенным эффектом AERO. Что именно интересует - заголовок окна всегда прозрачный или полупрозрачный, и на нем написаны буквы которые хорошо видны. При этом вокруг букв идет такое легкое высветление, что бы буквы были видны в не зависимости от фона, который за окном (сзади, за окном. т.к. окно полупрозрачное - фон может помешать чтению букв)

Что бы лучше представить (обратите внимания на надпись - Калькулятор)

[image]

Как написать div для css, в который можно обернуть текст, что бы на HTML странице получить такой же эффект?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
box-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff;
```

Примените такой стиль к диву. А также можно использовать text-shadow

Answer (score 1):

atnartur, переправь пожалуйста ответ на text-shadow. Все подошло, спасибо! (box-shadow - так себе способ). Переделал для себя - получилось черные буквы на черном фоне. Видно не так хорошо как я хотел, но тем не менее.

```
<table style="background-color:#000000; font-size:62px;">
<tr><td><div style="text-shadow: 0px 0px 24px #FFF;">
kill me... kill me please !!1
</div></td></tr></table>
```